# fedora 21 lets a user overwrite a file he does not have access to

Tags: linux, permissions, fedora, ext4, sqlite

I reproduced this problem on two fedora 21 machines.

I would like that `sqlite3` does not write the `~/.sqlite_history` file. I couldn't find an option but said, no matter, I'll make it that it can't write.

However it still can write and I don't get it.

```
~$  which sqlite3
/usr/bin/sqlite3
~$  ls -l /usr/bin/sqlite3
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 69456 Nov 25 12:00 /usr/bin/sqlite3
~$  ls -l .sqlite_history
ls: cannot access .sqlite_history: No such file or directory
~$  touch .sqlite_history
~$  sudo chown root .sqlite_history
[sudo] password for emmanuel:
~$  sudo chmod 600 .sqlite_history
~$  sudo chgrp root .sqlite_history
~$  ls -l .sqlite_history
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Jan  7 08:45 .sqlite_history
~$  whoami
emmanuel
~$  groups
emmanuel wheel
~$ echo test > .sqlite_history 
bash: .sqlite_history: Permission denied
~$  sqlite3 test.db
SQLite version 3.8.7.2 2014-11-18 20:57:56
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> select * from server;
Error: no such table: server
sqlite>
~$  cat .sqlite_history
select * from server;
~$  ls -l .sqlite_history
-rw------- 1 emmanuel emmanuel 22 Jan  7 08:45 .sqlite_history
$ mount | grep home
/dev/sda7 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

I also tried a symbolic link to `/dev/null` and also in that case sqlite3 simply overwrites the file?? What is going on? How come sqlite manages to overwrite that file?

I made the `ls` on the `sqlite3` binary to check that it is indeed not suid root and it's not. I don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't write to that file, but assuming it can write to the directory it can just delete the file and create a new one.

You don't need to be able to write to a file in order to delete it under the linux privilege model because deleting a file doesn't change it in any way - it changes the directory that contains the file. So it is the directory you need to be able to write to in order to delete a file.

Comment: wow, thanks a lot! I never knew that. Any hint maybe how could I work around and prevent sqlite3 from creating that history file as I was hoping to?

Comment: A workaround would be to protect your home directory so you can't write to it, by `chmod u-w "$HOME"`. (This will change the protection from 700 to 500, or from 711 to 511, or from 755 to 555, ....) In theory sqlite3 could overcome this by chmoding the directory back, but it probably isn't programmed to do so. Of course this will prevent _you_ from writing in your home directory, too.

Answer (score 1):

Try using "sudo chattr +i /.sqlite_history" This will prevent anything (even root) from modifying the target file. The i stands for "immutable" and is used regularly to keep DHCP from overwriting /etc/resolv.conf

This should do the trick for you. For more information: "man chattr". It's a tool that lets you set all sorts of wonderful file attributes!

Good Luck

Comment: wow, great suggestion, it works great! Thanks a lot! I'll leave the answer to TomH though as he answered the original question. Wish I could +10 you though :-)